# How commands are processed in LINUX

Tags: linux, kernel

I am new to LINUX. This question sounds simple and stupid, but I suppose this has a lot of meaning behind it. "HOW COMMANDS ARE PROCESSED IN LINUX?". Which means suppose if I give ls command,what makes it to display list of all files inside the directory?. I have been searching for the answer, and I could not find any clear explanation for the same. Please help me to solve the same.

Comment: This is way too broad. Are you asking about how the shell forks a new process and executes the specified command, or how the kernel itself manages processes, or how particular programmes do what they do?

Comment: maybe he/she just want to know what is a shell and how the shell parses the user command

Comment: I am asking what is the back-end operation performed when I execute a command

Comment: you may find this somewhat useful, if you want to dig into the details http://linuxgazette.net/111/ramankutty.html

Comment: Your question can be expressed in three words, "how computers work?" This is way too broad. This site mainly deals with specific problems in your code. If you don't have or plan to write any code, you came to a wrong place.

Comment: is it that hard? an OS is a software program and the shell is the interactive program that receives commands and executes them. :-)

Comment: Maybe a part of your question is answered using the strace command. This shows the system calls that a program make to the kernel. For example `strace ls` gives some nice output. Use `man strace` or `strace -h` to see some more info about what strace does and how it works. On OSX you can use dtruss instead of strace.

Comment: Maybe also this is also usefull for you: http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-linux-works-ultimate-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new too. But I can answer this in a top level.(not too many details).

Everything in Linux is file, which means that the `ls` is also a file. You can type `which ls`
and you can see the file's location.

So, a command is a file, when you type and Enter, the system will search for the file in your PATH and execute it. When the file is executed, it will talk with the kernel and tell the kernel what resources it wants to use, and then the kernel will talk with the real hardware and let the computer do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Some commands are shell keywords or shell builtins, so the shell (the program that accepts your commands) recognizes and processes them directly. Many other commands are executable programs found in the path; so, for example, if you enter `ls`, an executable called `ls` is executed (usually found in `/bin`, many commands cann be found in `/usr/bin/`). A command could also be an alias for another command.

You can use `type` command to find out what kind a command is, e.g.
`type ls`.